# How I can avoid using "global" with asyncio (telethon)?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

As far as I know using "global" is a bad practice in python, but I have no idea how to avoid it here.
Thank you in advance.

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events

api_id = ***
api_hash = '***'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash).start()

channel_id = ***

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_id))
async def handler(event):
    text = event.raw_text.lower()

    global task

    if text == 'start':
        task = client.loop.create_task(main())
        await client.send_message(channel_id, 'task was started')

    if text == 'stop':
        task.cancel()
        await client.send_message(channel_id, 'task was canceled')

async def main():
    while True:
        await client.send_message(channel_id, 'do something')
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Usually people use class variables instead of globals, and just pass around a reference to that class. Or, you could have the class contain all your variables _and_ logic, so you wouldn't even have to pass around a reference. Of course, this is with the condition that you should guard against race conditions and other threading pitfalls, which you'd have to do if it was global anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, I couldn't find the recommended way to use the client with classes, but you should always be able to connect it yourself. For example:

```
class MyClient:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.task = None
        self.client = client

    async def on_message(self, channel_id, event):
        text = event.raw_text.lower()

        if text == 'start':
            self.task = self.client.loop.create_task(self.main(channel_id))
            await self.client.send_message(channel_id, 'task was started')

        if text == 'stop':
            self.task.cancel()
            await self.client.send_message(channel_id, 'task was canceled')

    async def main(self, channel_id):
        while True:
            await self.client.send_message(channel_id, 'do something')
            await asyncio.sleep(3)

def run_client():
    # instantiate telegram client, my client, and connect the two
    api_id = ***
    api_hash = '***'

    channel_id = ***

    client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash).start()
    my_client = MyClient(client)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_id))
    async def handle(event):
        await my_client.on_message(channel_id, event)

    client.run_until_disconnected()

run_client()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I got a few errors. We must pass "client" and "channel_id" (if I place it in def run_client()) to the class. Could you edit your code? (sorry for trivial questions, I'm a beginner)

Comment: @ExKaSeT I've now updated the code to include `client` in the constructor. I also made it send `channel_id` to `on_message` rather than to the constructor of `MyClient`, so that you can have different channel_ids in the same client. If that doesn't make sense for your case because you'll only ever have one channel_id, you can easily change the code to send channel_id to the constructor as well.

Comment: @ExKaSeT I've now noticed that `main()` also requires `client` and `channel_id`, so I've made it a method on `MyClient` so it can access other parts of the class as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I made some edits and everything worked! Isn't there an easier way to do this without using global (maybe special asyncio functions)?

Comment: @ExKaSeT asyncio has no problems with classes and methods. It's the telegram API based on decorators that makes that a bit harder. There might be a simpler way, but I don't know it. If someone shows one, please accept that answer.

Comment: You can also use `client.add_event_handler` inside the `__init__`, `@client.on()` is just sugar for that but not mandatory. In a similat fashion, your custom class can have async methods to do things like start the client or run until disconnected as you need, and then use those.

Comment: @Lonami Perhaps you can write an answer that adapts the code in my answer according to your suggestion. It would be a nice resource to have for future visitors to the site, as it's not completely obvious from the documentation. What was perhaps originally meant as mere convenience functions are now perceived as the primary interface to the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

the TelegramClient's function:add_event_handler is what you're looking for

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32478499)

Answer (score 0):

In general in Python, if you need a variable to be "static" (continue its lifetime beyond a single function call) like "task" in this example, you should consider going for an object-oriented approach, like @user4815162342 suggested. If you don't want classes and objects, you can also emulate a similar functionality using pre-set keyword arguments, although it's somewhat of an ugly hack. In your example, you would only have to change a single function like so:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_id))
async def handler(event, static_variables={}):
    text = event.raw_text.lower()

    if text == 'start':
        static_variables['task'] = client.loop.create_task(main())
        await client.send_message(channel_id, 'task was started')

    if text == 'stop':
        static_variables['task'].cancel()
        await client.send_message(channel_id, 'task was canceled')
```

The reason this works is that Python will only instantiate default arguments for keyword arguments on the first function call, and then re-use the instance (in this example, an initially empty dictionary) on all subsequent function calls.